# Spectrum colormap for multiple curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I have been using `matlab2tikz` to generate a lot of my plots, but I am finding it struggling at this particular job so would like to inquire about how to do it properly in `pgfplots / tikz`.

Essentially I would like to plot a number of curves on one graph, and have a spectrum color map color them with colors evenly distributed on the spectrum. In MATLAB this is quite simple:

```
figure
const = linspace(0,pi/4,50)';
x = linspace(0,pi,128);
plots = sin(-const*x)';
noOfLines = length(const);
cmp = jet(noOfLines);
hLine = plot(plots);
for line = 1:noOfLines
set(hLine(line),'Color',cmp(line,:));
end
set(hLine,'LineWidth',1.5);
```

[image: matlab colormap]

I can export this with matlab2tikz and compile it which produces this gorgeous plot:

[image: tikzPlot]

The problem is the tikz code is kind of brute forced. It starts with 50 costumed `\definecolor`

```
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.00000,0.53846}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.00000,0.00000,0.61538}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.00000,0.07692,1.00000}% ...
```

for each color that is going to be used, and then 50 `\addplot`

```
\addplot [color=mycolor2,solid,line width=1.5pt,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{1 0\\
2   -0.000396497032881626\\
3   -0.000792994003429991\\
```

to plot each line with the correct color. I understand I am asking an aweful lot from `matlab2tikz` so I guess I would like to know how to do this properly using tikz / pgfplots. I have another data set that is similar but it has a lot more plots and comes out to 1.3 mb, taking a long time to compile.

I am happy with creating a `pgfplot` from a dataset that is in a text file with just the raw data (which would be the `plots` matrix in my MATLAB workspace in the above example), but have no idea how to proceed from here. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

In `MATLAB` my code will be in the workspace like:

[image: matlab workspace]

I then `dlmwrite` it to a .dat file by:

```
dlmwrite('data.dat',myData,'delimiter', '\t');
```

Then I try to `\addplot3` and get:

[image: plot]

This is my dataset:

```
0.99934 1.0005  1.0007  1.0001  0.99934
1.0029  1.0012  0.99933 0.99862 0.9979
1.0013  0.9988  1.0023  0.99525 0.99771
0.99774 0.99582 0.9943  0.99217 0.98699
0.9912  0.98502 0.97814 0.96116 0.94135
0.97022 0.94084 0.89332 0.83747 0.77688
0.88784 0.75475 0.61326 0.462   0.3339
0.58506 0.30003 0.11623 0.034422    0.0078042
0.099072    0.0090417   0.0031278   0.00023727  0.00050435
-0.0014491  0.00053296  -0.00028736 -0.0021953  0.00056537
-0.0024348  5.2456e-05  0.001471    5.6913e-05  -0.0010844
0.0019199   -0.0023666  0.00065858  -2.7668e-05 0.00034113
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I think you are using tabs for delimiter but you are telling this to pgfplots. Whitespace separators work just fine.

Comment: Hi @percusse, I have tried with `[col sep=tab]` but still get the same picture. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `const` variable appears to be like a `y` variable and the plotted function is actually `f(x,y) = sin(-x*y)`.

This can be plotted directly in `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.11,
    trig format plots=rad,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={0}{0},
        enlarge z limits=false,
        enlarge x limits=upper,
        colormap/jet,
    ]
    \addplot3[
        mesh,
        patch type=line,
        domain=0:pi,samples=128,
        domain y=0:pi/4, samples y=50,
        point meta=y,
    ]
    {sin(-y*x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The key ideas are to make a 3D mesh plot, and visualize the mesh lines by means of their scanlines (i.e. `patch type=line`) and show only the X/Z plane. I used `point meta=y` in order to define the y coordinate as color data.

**EDIT**

The same approach is possible if you place the data matrix into a table:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.11,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={0}{0},
        enlarge z limits=false,
        enlarge x limits=upper,
        colormap/jet,
    ]
    \addplot3[
        mesh,
        patch type=line,
        point meta=y,
    ]
    table {P.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The data table contains the same data, it is of the form

```
0.0e0 0.0e0 0.0e0 0.0e0
2.47371e-2 0.0e0 0.0e0 0.0e0
4.94742e-2 0.0e0 0.0e0 0.0e0
7.42113e-2 0.0e0 0.0e0 0.0e0
9.8948401e-2 0.0e0 0.0e0 0.0e0
1.23685501e-1 0.0e0 0.0e0 0.0e0
1.4842259e-1 0.0e0 0.0e0 0.0e0
1.7315968e-1 0.0e0 0.0e0 0.0e0
1.9789677e-1 0.0e0 0.0e0 0.0e0
[...]
3.0673993e0 0.0e0 0.0e0 0.0e0
3.0921364e0 0.0e0 0.0e0 0.0e0
3.1168735e0 0.0e0 0.0e0 0.0e0
3.1416106e0 0.0e0 0.0e0 0.0e0

0.0e0 1.60283e-2 0.0e0 1.60283e-2
2.47371e-2 1.60283e-2 -3.8e-4 1.60283e-2
4.94742e-2 1.60283e-2 -8.0e-4 1.60283e-2
7.42113e-2 1.60283e-2 -1.19e-3 1.60283e-2
9.8948401e-2 1.60283e-2 -1.59e-3 1.60283e-2
[...]
```

It is given in scanlines (please ignore the fourth column; I exported it together with my color data which is the y coordinate). The precise format is described in the pgfplots manual (section about 3d plots).

NOTE: pgfplots cannot transpose the data file. Consequently, it will only show scanlines along a specific axis. You will need to transpose it if it does not fit.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for your reply. I must not have been quite clear enough in my question though. What I am actually after is a method to do this, but taking data from an external file, that is not generated by a mathematical expression (that was just for an example). So my x-y data sets will be in columns in an external text file and added like in 3.3.1 of the manual `Getting the Data into TeX`. So basically each `\addplot table` needs to be added with the right color set I am thinking, but this is where I am lost. Thanks

Comment: That works in the same way; see my edit.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks. I am still having problems getting this working sorry. My data comes from `MATLAB` in the form of columns. Each column being a, x-y plot. I save it and use your code but only get one funny looking plot. I have updated my question with just an example of what is going on. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You are right, the details of the 3d table format make the difference here... I posted this as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198639/how-can-i-import-matrix-data-2d-function-from-matlab-into-pgfplots/198640#198640 together with an in-depth answer.