# How can I import matrix data (2d function) from matlab into pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, import, matlab2tikz

This question arised in [Spectrum colormap for multiple curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197934/spectrum-colormap-for-multiple-curves/198050#comment460055_198050), but since it is of general interest, I add a separate question and my answer here.

Suppose you have a matlab figure which needs to be converted to `pgfplots`. The matlab figure contains a 2d function `f(x,y)` which is typically visualized as a matrix.

Suppose it is given as

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid( linspace(-1,1,3), linspace(4,5,5) );
Z = X + Y;
surf(X,Y,Z)
shading interp
```

such that

```
octave:7> Z
Z =

   3.0000   4.0000   5.0000
   3.2500   4.2500   5.2500
   3.5000   4.5000   5.5000
   3.7500   4.7500   5.7500
   4.0000   5.0000   6.0000
```

and the outcome is

[image]

I would like to reproduce that in `pgfplots`. To this end, I saved the `Z` matrix as ascii and imported it into an `\addplot3 table` statement:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[surf] table {
  3.0000   4.0000   5.0000
   3.2500   4.2500   5.2500
   3.5000   4.5000   5.5000
   3.7500   4.7500   5.7500
   4.0000   5.0000   6.0000

    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which leads to the unexpected result

[image]

How can I reproduce my intented surface plot?

Comment: [related question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411110/pgfplots-reshape-a-matrix-of-data-before-conditional-3d-surface-plotting), however with a different definition of the data format for x and y values (only z as matrix). I am not sure what data format is described here except that is is from matlab. (This comment is mainly for the purpose of linking the two questions.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pgfplots` expects a different input format, namely a table of the form

```
X Y Z
. . .
. . .
. . .
```

in which the matrix data is *serialized* into a long stream. It resembles matlab's `matrix(:)` syntax.

Consequently, you can export you data by means of

```
data = [ X(:) Y(:) Z(:) ]
save -ascii P.dat data
% save P.dat data -ASCII

size(Z)

data =

  -1.00000   4.00000   3.00000
  -1.00000   4.25000   3.25000
  -1.00000   4.50000   3.50000
  -1.00000   4.75000   3.75000
  -1.00000   5.00000   4.00000
   0.00000   4.00000   4.00000
   0.00000   4.25000   4.25000
   0.00000   4.50000   4.50000
   0.00000   4.75000   4.75000
   0.00000   5.00000   5.00000
   1.00000   4.00000   5.00000
   1.00000   4.25000   5.25000
   1.00000   4.50000   5.50000
   1.00000   4.75000   5.75000
   1.00000   5.00000   6.00000

ans =

   5   3
```

and use

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colorbar,view={-60}{30}, colormap/jet,shader=interp]
    \addplot3[surf,mesh/rows=5,mesh/ordering=y varies] table {
 -1.00000000e+00 4.00000000e+00 3.00000000e+00
 -1.00000000e+00 4.25000000e+00 3.25000000e+00
 -1.00000000e+00 4.50000000e+00 3.50000000e+00
 -1.00000000e+00 4.75000000e+00 3.75000000e+00
 -1.00000000e+00 5.00000000e+00 4.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 4.00000000e+00 4.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 4.25000000e+00 4.25000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 4.50000000e+00 4.50000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 4.75000000e+00 4.75000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 5.00000000e+00 5.00000000e+00
 1.00000000e+00 4.00000000e+00 5.00000000e+00
 1.00000000e+00 4.25000000e+00 5.25000000e+00
 1.00000000e+00 4.50000000e+00 5.50000000e+00
 1.00000000e+00 4.75000000e+00 5.75000000e+00
 1.00000000e+00 5.00000000e+00 6.00000000e+00
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

where the data table is the contents of `P.dat` (could have been imported using `\addplot3[...] table {P.dat};` as well). The key is that we need to tell `pgfplots` how to read the file: we need to say at least one of the matrix dimensions (`mesh/rows=5` here) and we need to say how it is linearized (`mesh/ordering=y varies` in our case because that's how the matrix is lineared by means of `data(:)`). The outcome is

[image]

The view argument is imprecise (I suppose it is of less importance here).

---

For the sake of completeness (the original question in [Spectrum colormap for multiple curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197934/spectrum-colormap-for-multiple-curves/198050#comment460055_198050) was about line plots), I also show how to use `patch type=line` here in order to show each scanline as a line plot with individual color:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colorbar,view={-60}{30}, colormap/jet,shader=interp]

    \addplot3[
        mesh,
        mesh/rows=5,mesh/ordering=y varies,
        patch type=line,
        point meta=x,
    ]
    table {
 -1.00000000e+00 4.00000000e+00 3.00000000e+00
 -1.00000000e+00 4.25000000e+00 3.25000000e+00
 -1.00000000e+00 4.50000000e+00 3.50000000e+00
 -1.00000000e+00 4.75000000e+00 3.75000000e+00
 -1.00000000e+00 5.00000000e+00 4.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 4.00000000e+00 4.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 4.25000000e+00 4.25000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 4.50000000e+00 4.50000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 4.75000000e+00 4.75000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 5.00000000e+00 5.00000000e+00
 1.00000000e+00 4.00000000e+00 5.00000000e+00
 1.00000000e+00 4.25000000e+00 5.25000000e+00
 1.00000000e+00 4.50000000e+00 5.50000000e+00
 1.00000000e+00 4.75000000e+00 5.75000000e+00
 1.00000000e+00 5.00000000e+00 6.00000000e+00
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here, `point meta` plays the role of "color data". In this case, color data is from the `x` column that is: each scanline has the same color. If you want to have scan lines along `y`, you would need to transpose `X`, `Y`, and `Z` before exporting them to `pgfplots`.

[image]

Comment: Hi Christian. I got this example working, but am still having troubles with my data set. I am a bit confused about the X, Y and Z axis considering my data is only X and Y. In my case, the x axis and y axis data can be generated in `MATLAB` using the following: tau = linspace(0.001,1,20);   data = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)exp(-x.*tau),[1:0.1:2]','UniformOutput',0)); `data` now contains 20 columns of data, all to be plotted vs `tau`, as done in `MATLAB` using plot(tau,data).  From here I have tried a few things but still cant reproduce the `MATLAB` plot in pgfplots. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds as if you can use `[X,Y] = meshgrid([1:0.1:2], linspace(0.001,1,20)); Z = exp(-X.*Y)` and proceed according to my answer. The procedure with mesh grid combined with matrix operations is matlab's way to generate two dimensional functions -- `arrayfun` is "useful for functions that do not accept array arguments.  If the function does    accept array arguments it is better to call the function directly." (from its documentation). Alternatively, you can generate the missing `X` and `Y` matrices using `repmat` (if I remember correctly).

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for your time. I apologize as I must not have been very clear in my question. My MATLAB code was just to generate 2-d data for the purpose of this question. In reality, my data comes out in the form of `x, y1, y2, y3, y4`. Of which the x is the x axis, and y are the individual plots I want superimpose on 1 plot in pgfplots. In this case there is no Z, so I do  not know how to proceed from here. I have uploaded an example here: http://pastebin.com/R8nC0zq4, if you could show me how to produce the plot using this example it will clear it up for me. Thanks

Comment: @SteveHatcher I think we have to state that my solution is difficult to fit to your use-case. Perhaps we should go back to the first step and re-answer your question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197934/spectrum-colormap-for-multiple-curves/198050#comment460055_198050 with our improved understanding? Perhaps we address your needs if you open another question like that, add your pastebin link and show the matlab code. This will allow me to step back and rethink about the problem. Maybe someone else contributes a good (different) solution which is better to apply than mine.

Comment: Hi Christian. Sure, I will post a new question and this time be more clear about what I want. Thanks for your solution though, it actually solved something which I would have asked down the track.