# pgfplots: Reshape a MATRIX of data before conditional 3D surface plotting

Tags: pgfplots

As far as I know, for plotting a surface using pgfplots, the data should be organized as follows:

```
x1 y1 z11
x1 y2 z12
x1 y3 z13
.  .   .
.  .   .
.  .   .
xn ym znm
```

However, usually, I get the data to be plotted in the following matrix shape

```
   y1  y2  y3   ...      ym
x1 z11 z12 z13  ...     z1m
x2 z21 z22 z23           .
x3 z31 z32 z33           .
.   .            .       .
.   .              .
.   .                .
xn zn1       ...        znm
```

So, is there any way to reshape or use the data as it is for plotting without having to manually organize it the way pgfplots expects?

---

This is an exemplary sample of data set to be conditionally surface plotted the same way done in [the answer to my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410997/2288).

```
     0.8    0.78    0.76    0.74    0.72
3.1 12.17   11.5    100     100     100
3.3 12.17   11.5    11.5    100     100
3.5 12.17   11.5    11.5    11.5    100
3.7 12.17   11.5    11.5    11.5    11.5
3.9 12.17   11.5    11.5    11.5    11.5
4.1 12.17   11.5    11.5    11.5    11.5
```

---

### Edit 1

As suggested by [Christian Feuersänger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411110/pgfplots-reshape-the-data-before-conditional-surface-plotting?noredirect=1#comment1026713_411110), I made a script by MATLAB as follows to reshape the data, but I don't have any idea how to make its corresponding `lua` syntax.

```
Data=[
12.17   11.5    100     100     100;
12.17   11.5    11.5    100     100;
12.17   11.5    11.5    11.5    100;
12.17   11.5    11.5    11.5    11.5;
12.17   11.5    11.5    11.5    11.5;
12.17   11.5    11.5    11.5    11.5;
];

xvalues=3.1:0.2:4.1;
yvalues=0.8:-0.02:0.72;

ReshapedData=zeros(3,numel(Data)); % x y z

fileID = fopen('file.txt','w');% file to save data

for nx=1:length(xvalues)
    for my=1:length(yvalues)
        colno=my+(nx-1)*length(yvalues);
        ReshapedData(1,colno)=xvalues(nx);
        ReshapedData(2,colno)=yvalues(my);
        ReshapedData(3,colno)=Data(nx,my);
        fprintf( fileID,'%.1f\t%.2f\t%.2f\r\n',ReshapedData(:,colno) );
    end
        fprintf( fileID,'\r\n');
end
fclose(fileID);
```

Comment: You will need some scripting solution to reshape the data. This can be an external tool (like a python script) or an embedded script. Standard embedded scripting solutions in latex are: plain TeX (quite uncommon language and bad data structure support) or `lua`. Embedding scripting solutions with `lua` require you to invoke `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`. If you come up with a lua script, we can help you to inject the result into `\pgfplotstableread`.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Thanks for your suggestion. I have already made a script using MATLAB (Edit 1) since it is the most known language to me. So, i would be grateful if you could help me convert it to `lua`.

Comment: For the record: I have added a Feature Request for that to the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/76/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in some comments, this is possible with `lua`.

My script assumes data ordered as follows, whitespace-delimited only. This is basically as asked in the question. The indentation in the first line is optional.

```
   y1  y2  
x1 z11 z12
x2 z21 z22 
x3 z31 z32
```

The script reads the data, stores it in tables and writes the tables in an output file such that the data is reformated in the desired way.

```
x1 y1 z11 
x1 y2 z12 
x2 y1 z21 
x2 y2 z22 
x3 y1 z31 
x3 y2 z32
```

A minimal example code, where the input file with your example data and the `lua` script are included and written into files with the help of `filecontents`, reads as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents,luacode}

\begin{filecontents*}{mat-in.txt}
     0.8    0.78    0.76    0.74    0.72
3.1 12.17   11.5    100     100     100
3.3 12.17   11.5    11.5    100     100
3.5 12.17   11.5    11.5    11.5    100
3.7 12.17   11.5    11.5    11.5    11.5
3.9 12.17   11.5    11.5    11.5    11.5
4.1 12.17   11.5    11.5    11.5    11.5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents}{mat-rewrite.lua}
\begin{luacode}

function rewrite_mat(infilename, outfilename)
  infile  = io.open( infilename, "r")
  outfile = io.open(outfilename, "w")

  ynum = 0
  xnum = -1
  yvals={}
  xvals={}
  zvals={}

  for line in infile:lines() do
    t={}                               -- make a table from the line (whitespace-delimited)
    length=1
    for v in string.gmatch(line, "%S+") do
      t[length]=v
      length = length + 1
    end 

    xnum = xnum + 1                    -- count number of x values 

    if xnum < 1 then                   -- first line: count number of y values
      ynum  = length -1
      yvals = t
    else
      xvals[xnum]=t[1]                 -- all other lines: store x and z values
      for y=1,ynum do
        index = ynum*(xnum-1)+y
        zvals[index]=t[y+1]
      end
    end
  end

  infile:close()

  for x = 1,xnum do
    for y = 1,ynum do
      outfile:write(xvals[x] .. " " .. yvals[y] .. " " .. zvals[(x-1)*ynum+y] .. " " .. "\string\n")
    end
  end

  outfile:close()

end  
\end{luacode}
\end{filecontents}

% load function
\input{mat-rewrite.lua}

% run function mat-in.txt for structure, mat-in2 for matrix with values
\directlua{rewrite_mat("mat-in.txt","out.txt")}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[mesh/ordering=y varies, unbounded coords=jump,]
\addplot3[surf,mesh/rows=5] 
  table[
        x index =0,
        y index =1,
        % use an expression to state that z values of 100 should be ignored
        z expr={\thisrowno{2} == 100 ? NaN : \thisrowno{2}},
       ] {out.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have reused [the code from the previous question/answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410997/44467) to drop the `z=100` values. The output plot of this example looks not very spectacular... But it demonstrates the conversion from the matrix data to a vector and subsequent plotting.

[image]

Comment: +1 Very nice solution. As I stated in [the comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411110/pgfplots-reshape-a-matrix-of-data-before-conditional-3d-surface-plotting#comment1026760_411110) I made a [Feature Request](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/76/) in the PGFPlots Tracker regarding this issue. Do you think you could generalize your solution? Or even better: Would you be able to *implement* this features into PGFPlots?

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow  I can for sure try to integrate it but first i will generalize it.i have comment chars, custom table delimiters and a bit of configurability regarding table structure in mind,  how x and y values are ordered around the matrix. Any other suggestions?

Comment: i should also directly extract `mesh/rows` and `mesh/cols`.

Comment: Many thanks for your willingness to implement that feature! I suggest that we continue the discussion about the implementation in the comments to the feature-request. It fits better there than here. About other suggestions: There could be the possibility that only the z-values of the matrix are given. If you have "moved" the comments to the tracker I will contact Christian (the author of PGFPlots) as well that he should comment on the needed features as well. He has -- of course -- a much deeper insight than me.